# How to select <tr> that has <td>'s only, but not <th> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `table` with headers and table data. Essentially look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12:00 am</td><td>01:00 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01:00 am</td><td>02:00 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12:00 pm</td><td>01:00 am</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to select data rows only. Header row should not be selected. I don't want to add a class to my `td` or `tr` elements

I have to do this in JQuery, so JQuery specific solution is acceptable too.

Any clue.

Comment: Can you change the HTML to use a `thead`?

Comment: You say in your title and tags that you're looking to do this in CSS, but you say in your description that you have to do this in jQuery. Which one is it?

Comment: I updated the title to reflect his question, as this cannot be done in CSS, but it can in jQuery.

Comment: I update it to '...using CSS selector' but it is again changed to '...using jQuery'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:has` selector to get tr that have td elements in it:

```
$('tr:has(td)').css('name','value')
```